# Martingale whose distribution is independent of n

Tags: probability, martingales

*Claim: A one-point stationary sequence $(X_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ of square integrable r.v's is a martingale w.r.t the natural filtration iff it is surely constant in time.*

I am convinced that this is a false statement, and therefore I'd like to provide a counterexample. As a simple counterexample I wanted to take a sequence of $i.i.d. ~ Bernoulli(p)$. 
Then $E[X_{n+1} | \mathcal{F}_n$] = $E[X_{n+1}] = E[X_n] = p$, independent of $n$, and therefore one-point stationary. On the other hand, $P(X_{n+1} = X_{n}) \neq 1$.

As I'm not very familiar yet with martingales, I am wondering if the sequence of Bernoulli i.i.d. r.v's is indeed a martingale, and if it suffices as a counterexample to disprove the claim.

*EDIT*: $E[X_{n+1} | \mathcal{F}_n] = E[X_n] = p \neq X_n$. Therefore, this sequence is not a martingale. What is an appropriate counterexample?

Comment: I don't know what one-point stationat means but your sequence is certainly not a martingale. We need to have $E[X_{n+1}\mid \mathcal F_n] =X_n$. But in your case we don't have that unless $p=1$ or $p=0$.

Comment: One point stationary means that for any $n$ the distribution of $X_n$ does not depend on $n$. Indeed, you're right, I made a mistake there. Can you give me a hint on how I can find a martingale which serves as a counterexample?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$E(X_{n+1}|\mathcal F_n) =X_n$. So $X_n^{2}=(E(X_{n+1}|\mathcal F_n))^{2} \leq E(X^{2}_{n+1}|\mathcal F_n)$. Since both sides have the same expecatation (by stationarity) we get $X_n^{2}= E(X^{2}_{n+1}|\mathcal F_n)$. Now $E((X_{n+1}-X_n)^{2} |\mathcal F_n)=E(X^{2}_{n+1} |\mathcal F_n)-2X_nE(X_{n+1} |\mathcal F_n)+X_n^{2}=0$ and taking expectation we get $X_{n+1}=X_n$ a.s.

Comment: Thank you! It seems my intuition was completely wrong here.

Answer (score 2):

You have
$$
\eqalign{
E[(X_{n+1}-X_n)^2] 
&= E[X_{n+1}^2]+E[X_n^2]-2E[X_{n+1}X_n]\cr
&=2E[X_n^2]-2E[X_{n+1}X_n]\cr
&=2E[X_n^2]-2E[X_nX_n]=0,\cr
}
$$
the second equality because of 1-point stationarity and the third because $X_n$ is a martingale.

Comment: How can we conclude from $E[(X_{n+1} - X_n)^2] = 0$ that $P(X_n = X_{n+1}) = 1$? I was looking for $E[X_{n+1}^2] = E[X_n^2]$  $\forall n \in \mathbb{N}$. How do we do it in case $E[(X_{n+1} - X_n)^2] = 0$? I know that $E[(X_{n+1} - X_n)^2] = 0$ means convergence in $L^2$. Do we use this to show that there exists a subsequence converging almost surely?

Comment: If $E[(X_{n+1}-X_n)^2]=0$ then $(X_{n+1}-X_n)^2=0$ a.s., so $|X_{n+1}-X_n|=0$ a.s., so $X_{n+1} = X_n$ a.s.

Answer (score 1):

If they are one-point stationary, there are a lot of things we can do with them to show there invariance.
In this case, you have further that they're square-integrable, which makes thing even easier. 
Just observe that:
$E[X_{n+1}^2]= E[X_n^2]+E[ (X_n-X_{n+1})^2]$ 
Done

Comment: I'm sorry, I cannot completely follow you in the first part. How do you get the equality $E[X^2_{n+1}] = E[X_n^2] + E[(X_n - X_{n+1})^2]$?